# Using `env` command with `eval`

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables, eval

Suppose I have this in `script.sh`:

```bash
env -i SOMEVAR=SOMEVALUE eval -- "$@"
```

I run it with:

```bash
./script.sh echo "\$SOMEVAR"
```

Now it shows:

```bash
env: ‘eval’: No such file or directory
```

I suppose it doesn't work because `eval` is a Bash builtin.

Any way to make `env` work with `eval`?

Comment: `env` expect a command (so on PATH), but you provide with a keyword. Just replace it with `sh eval`.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi If using `sh`, why bother with `eval` at all?

Comment: @Kusalananda: you are totally correct. I was just giving the generic answers, and I miss that to add that this is special.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you even want `eval`? Just use the shell:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/sh
env -i SOMEVAR=SOMEVALUE  sh -c "$@"
```

Then you run it like this:

```
$ foo.sh 'echo $SOMEVAR'
SOMEVALUE
```

Comment: Can I call the script without the quotes? (i.e. `foo.sh echo '$SOMEVAR'`)

Comment: @sudoer if you change `sh -c "$@"` to `sh -c "$*"`, yes. But it is better to just make sure you quote things.

Comment: Another problem: The arguments supplied to the script must not have spaces. Fix?

Comment: @sudoer yes, _quote your input_. Or ask a new question and show the actual command you want to run and explain why you are using such a complicated approach. I suspect this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101) and if you tell us _why_ you want this we can give you a better solution.

Comment: I _think_ i found a solution. But I am unavailable to try it out now. I'll test it tmr :)